# Thumbnails in Blender's file menu

Tags: interface, customization

Although I have checked thumbnails in preferences:

[image]

I do not get thumbnails in Blender's file menu:

[image]

So, I still always have to manually select thumbnails when opening/appending files. (How) Can I change this?

**Edit:**
I'd like to see thumbnails for .blend files each time I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> without having to select them manually over and over again:

[image]

Comment: *Show thumbnails* will show them for images and movies (which is written on its tooltip). What are you trying to preview with thumbnail?

Comment: @marcus what Mr Zak means is that setting is not meant to rule the generali "file open" window, but only the one you get when opening images/movies in dedicated editors (liek UV/image editor)

Comment: I got what Mr. Zak meant and have edited my question. I'd like to always see files' thumbnails everywhere in Blender.

Comment: you could file a feature request, (https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Contact#Requesting_Features). It could be in 2.8 perhaps.

Comment: Okay, perhaps I am suggesting it. (Mailing lists and IRC are not things I am usually using...)

Comment: This is not currently supported and is a known limiation. Please don't use developer mailing lists for  feature requests, use https://rightclickselect.com instead if you must.

Comment: "Known limitation" sounds good... Seeing thumbnails is definitely very useful.